# How to read both landscape and portrait dimen value programmatically

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a dimen value like this:

```
file: sw720dp/dimens.xml

<resources>
    <dimen name="view_width">640dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and same for landscape:

```
file: sw720dp-land/dimens.xml

<resources>
    <dimen name="view_width">720dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I know that for current orientation I get one of them doing this:

```
viewWidth = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_horizontal_padding);
```

But the question is how to get to the other one? I need the second value or the 
smaller one to calculate the difference between them. Is it possible programmatically?

Comment: I'd put both needed values in each file, and name the other value appropriately i.e. the "other" one is most likely "height".

Comment: @Andy I haven't thought about that.... this isn't the cleanest solution but should do the trick. Thanks :)